# Vfp Report to jpg

Tags: visual-foxpro

I am trying to export vfp report to jpg using foxypreviewer .

Im using this syntax

```
DO foxypreviewer.app

LABEL FORM report object type 11 TO ab
```

It is converting all pages in single pdf.

I need to save all pages in separately jpg files in single folder through my code .

Foxypreviewer SaveAs images Feature provides same process which i need.

Is this possible. If yes please share your knowledge.

Thanks

Comment: I don't know anything about foxypreviewer but they do have some documentation on their web site.  The one thing that caught my eye is this code sample...DO FOXYPREVIEWER.APP _Screen.oFoxyPreviewer.lRepeatInPage = .T. 
REPORT FORM YourReport PREVIEW.  Notice in the second line there is a reference to the FoxyPreviewer on the screen.  I wonder if there is a property within that object that allows you to do what you need.

Comment: Any other solution, I want to export report to jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I doubt there's a good way to do it directly from within VFP.  A search on Google for "convert pdf to jpg" shows some results, though, so maybe you could accomplish your goal in several steps.

Answer (score 0):

You can use as well the foxypreviewer to achieve the conversion of any vfp report (frx) to images (1 or more)
try this code :

```
local m.yrep
m.yrep= addbs(justpath(sys(16,1)))
do locfile('Foxypreviewer.app',"app")
LOCAL loReport as "PreviewHelper" OF ("FoxyPreviewer.app" )
loReport = CREATEOBJECT("PreviewHelper")
WITH loReport as ReportHelper
SET POINT TO ","
SET DECIMALS TO 2
SET SEPARATOR TO "."
    .AddReport(getfile("frx"))
    .cDestFile =m.yrep+ "test.JPG"  
.RunReport()
local m.oo
m.oo=.cDestFile
ENDWITH
loReport = NULL
RELEASE loReport
run/n explorer  &oo
RETURN
```